# how to use getPriceHtml() in custom module with custom phtml

Tags: price, phtml

I have a custom module with custom phtml which will print the product. But it seems that, the below code

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
```

won't render any thing on that page. So I tried to change my code to

```
$product_block = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product;
echo $product_block->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
```

But it generated an  error message like this.

> Call to a member function getStoreLabel() on a non-object in lines XX

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: how did you configured your custom phtml file. Show the relevant layout update codes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hkinterview,

custom phtml  block class `should  need to extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`

```
then  `$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);` will be workss
```

example

```
class YoumoduleNamespace_yourModuleName_Block_yourclass extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this solution http://davemacaulay.com/call-this-getpricehtml-custom-magento-template/ if you cannot/don't want to extend some classes.